# How do I make it so that notepad++ will delete lines that have more than 2 words?

Tags: notepad++

How do I do it with notepad++, please and thank you, I need it so that it can delete more than 2 words per line?

Comment: Have you tried a regex find and replace?

Comment: What is a word for you? Only letters? Letters + digits? Only ASCII letters? May contain letters like `àéèçùâêûñ`...? What separators between words? Spaces, punctations ...

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/q/1464799/763386) and give sample text and expected result. Like this your question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to enter the Replace dialog and click the Mark tab.

In the tab click on "Bookmark line", on
"Regular expressions" and on ". matches newline".

Enter in "Find what": `^\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+.\n`
and click Mark All.

When the lines are all marked, use the menu
*Search > Bookmark > Remove Bookmarked Lines*.

Make a backup copy of the file before starting.

[image]

Comment: It gives me 0 matches

Comment: It assumes white space between words. If your text is different, add an example to the post.

Comment: @Anaksunaman: Already advised.